# Python unicode codepoint to unicode character

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to write out to a flat file some Chinese, or Russian or various non-English character-sets for testing purposes. I'm getting stuck on how to output a Unicode hex-decimal or decimal value to its corresponding character.

For example in Python, if you had a hard coded set of characters like `абвгдежзийкл` you would assign `value = u"абвгдежзийкл"` and no problem.

If however you had a single decimal or hex decimal like 1081 / 0439 stored in a variable and you wanted to print that out with it's corresponding actual character (and not just output 0x439) how would this be done? The Unicode decimal/hex value above refers to `й`.

Comment: You might want to revise the title of your question. It mentions UTF-8, yet the question has nothing to do with UTF-8.

Comment: Your constant mention of "decimal or hex" makes be think that you are in ignorance of the fact that "decimal or hex" is just a matter of representation and not a property of the value itself.

Answer (score 40):

**Python 2**: Use [`unichr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr):

```
>>> print(unichr(1081))
й
```

**Python 3**:  Use [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> print(chr(1081))
й
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it's not what I'm looking for since I already know how to handle hard-coded entries. I want to know how to handle decimal or hex-decimal unicode values in a variable for standard output, or output to file.

Comment: @stoneferry: Just change the `1081` to the name of your variable that contains the character code.

Comment: If I has a variable that contained integer '1081' only, how would I for example use the print command to output the character and not jsut '1081'.

Comment: If your variable is a string with the hexadecimal form of a number, you can convert it to an int with `int(var, 16)`. For example, `int('0x0439', 16)` gives `1081`.

Comment: Note: [`unichr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) is only for Python 2. In Python 3, you can simply use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).

Answer (score 10):

So the answer to the question is:

1. convert the hexadecimal value to decimal with `int(hex_value, 16)`
2. then get the corresponding strin with `chr()`.

To sum up:

```
>>> print(chr(int('0x897F', 16)))
西
```

Comment: `0x` is optional if you explicitly specify the base, i.e. `chr(int('897F', 16))` will work too

Comment: why?   `chr(0x897F)` works fine.  `0x897F` is an integer literal https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals

Answer (score 3):

While working on a project that included parsing some JSONs, I encountered a similar problem. I had a lot of strings that had all non-ASCII characters escaped like this:

```
>>> print(content)
\u0412\u044B j\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0435 \u0438\u0437 \u0420\u043E\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0438?
...
>>> print(content)
\u010Cemu jesi na\u010Dinal izu\u010Dati med\u017Euslovjansky jezyk?
```

Converting such mixes symbol-by-symbol with `unichr()` would be tedious. The solution I eventually decided on:

```
content.encode("utf8").decode("unicode-escape")
```

The first operation (encoding) produces bytestrings like this:

```
b'\\u0412\\u044B j\\u0435\\u0441\\u0442\\u0435 \\u0438\\u0437 \\u0420\\u043E\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u0438?'
b'\\u010Cemu jesi na\\u010Dinal izu\\u010Dati med\\u017Euslovjansky jezyk?'
```

and the second operation (decoding) transforms the byte string into Unicode string but with `\\` replaced by `\`, which "unpacks" the characters, giving the result like this:

```
Вы jесте из России?
Čemu jesi načinal izučati medžuslovjansky jezyk?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into the error:

> ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)

While trying to convert your hex value using `unichr`, you can get around that error by doing something like:

```
>>> n = int('0001f600', 16)
>>> s = '\\U{:0>8X}'.format(n)
>>> s
'\\U0001F600'
>>> binary = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> print(binary)
```