# How to iterate a Unicode string in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a string, and I want to add unique non-ASCII characters to it. I need to do it in a loop because I may need to add more than one. The problem is that I don't know how to construct a proper Unicode string in the loop.

For example, I would like to add `\u2713`, `\u2714`, `\u2715` etc to my string. I'm not sure how to do it.

```
s = 'ABCD'

for j in range(10):        
    s = s + u'\u2713'
    #s = s + (u'\u2713' + j) # This doesn't work

print s
```

Comment: @JeremyBanks Copy and paste error. Fixing now...

Comment: Maybe [Python unicode codepoint to unicode character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715669/python-unicode-codepoint-to-unicode-character)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`unichr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) ([`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) in Python 3.x) to convert `int` to unicode string:

```
s = 'ABCD'

for i in range(10):
    s += unichr(0x2713 + i)

print s
```

prints `ABCD✓✔✕✖✗✘✙✚✛✜`

---

Instead of appending characters, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (or `unicode.join`):

```
s = 'ABCD' + u''.join(unichr(0x2713 + i) for i in range(10))
```

OR

```
s = 'ABCD' + u''.join(unichr(ch) for ch in range(0x2713, 0x271d))
```

OR

```
s = 'ABCD' + u''.join(map(unichr, range(0x2713, 0x271d)))
```