# Python - Best way to detect accent HTML escape in a string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Python has some good libraries to convert Unicode accent characters [to its closest Ascii character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string), as well as libraries to encode codepoint [to its Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715669/python-unicode-codepoint-to-unicode-character).

However, what options are there to check whether a string has unicode codepoint or HTML escape? For example, this string:

`Rialta te Venice&#199`

Has the `&#199`, which translates to a [latin capital letter C](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/199). Is there a python library that detects codepoints/escape within a string and outputs the Unicode equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you're asking, but here is my best try:

1. `&#199` is an *HTML escape*, which you can [unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360639/2111778) like so:

   ```py
   >>> s = 'Rialta te Venice&#199'
   >>> import html
   >>> s2 = html.unescape(s); s2
   'Rialta te VeniceÇ'
   ```
2. As you've said, there are libraries for [normalizing/removing accents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/2111778):

   ```py
   >>> import unidecode
   >>> unidecode.unidecode(s2)
   'Rialta te VeniceC'
   ```

   You don't really need to check if it has Unicode codepoints, as this function won't change non-accented characters. But you could check anyway using [`s2.isascii()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51141941/2111778).

So the complete solution is to use `unidecode.unidecode(html.unescape(s))`.

Comment: My question was essentially how to "undo" the ```&#199```, which I mistakenly thought was codepoint (when it is actually HTML escape, as you pointed out). Your answer works beautifully, as ```unescape(s)``` detects where an HTML escape exists - thank you!